# ERROR (no such process) Nginx+Gunicorn+Supervisord

Tags: nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

if I run command (to start the app) via supervisor:

```
sudo supervisorctl start myapp
```

it is throwing the error of:

```
myapp: ERROR (no such process)
```

I created a file called myappsettings.conf:

```
[program:myapp]
command = /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/gunicorn_config.py myapp.wsgi
user = ubuntu
stdout_logfile = /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/myapp/error/gunicorn_supervisor.log
redirect_stderr = true
```

What is the issue here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try:

```
supervisorctl reread
supervisorctl reload
```

That should start the service. I did this as root under Ubuntu 13.04.

EDIT:

I've had trouble since I posted this with SIGHUP'ing Supervisor processes. I would just like to share a little snippet I found elsewhere:

```
sudo kill -HUP `sudo supervisorctl status | grep $APP_NAME | sed -n '/RUNNING/s/.*pid \([[:digit:]]\+\).*/\1/p'`
```

The below will send a SIGHUP to the process running APP_NAME. This is useful for Gunicorn graceful reloading.

Joe

Comment: Wow... really did they have to NOT put this in the documentation? Thanks a bunch for your answer!

Comment: I found this helpful:  http://www.onurguzel.com/supervisord-restarting-and-reloading/

Comment: The problem is that this will restart all supervised processes, while restart command is meant to restart a single one.

Comment: The issue was with the reading of the config files. Its not a great option on a live system.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the gunicorns's process in supervisor is different from the name of gunicorn in truth which can be confusing, to reset gunicorn using supervisor use

```
sudo supervisorctl restart guni:gunicorn
```